# Oracle MAF numeric input

Tags: oracle-maf

I am trying to call a javascript function from a Oracle MAF amx file so that only numeric keys can be entered on an input field:

```
<amx:inputText required="true" showRequired="true" value="#{FSRBC.selectedFSR.time}">
  <amx:clientListener method="numbersOnly" type="keyDown"/>
</amx:inputText>
```

This calls a js function:

```
function numbersOnly (evt) {
  var _keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
  var _filterField = evt.getCurrentTarget();
  var _oldValue = _filterField.getValue();
  if (_keyCode > 64 && _keyCode < 91) {
    _filterField.setValue(_oldValue);
    evt.cancel();
  }
}
```

The js function is defined in its own file, validation.js which is listed in maf-feature.xml:

```
<adfmf:include type="JavaScript" file="resources/js/validation.js" id="i19"/>
```

However numbersOnly does not get called. I have added console.log and alert calls at the first line, which are not executed.

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write a separate script for the numeric keyboard. amx:inputText has a property inputType. Set "number" to it. It will show the only numeric keyboard. This property also supports email, tel, url.